# Need help to identify SOT23-5 component and equivalent suggest

Tags: identification, surface-mount

My projector controller board IC burned so I have to replace this IC. I cannot find this component, so please help me identify this IC.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this:

https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1811061726_Techcode-Semicon-TD6810B_C193721.pdf

It's a step down voltage regulator, available through LCSC.com

https://www.lcsc.com/products/DC-DC-Converters_484.html?keyword=6810b

Pin 2 on this part is ground, so if you can confirm that pin 2 does connect to ground that would add a measure of confidence.